# Ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop iso image

Tags: 12.04

I try to download ubuntu-14.04.2 desktop from

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

But after whole downloading the iso image, when I getting to burn it to a CD or install on a bootable USB it says not probable image.

Comment: Can you copy in the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: Check the md5sum of the download

Comment: Don't know whether its valid to mention this here but that Ubuntu version doesn't work with ATI drivers. 14.04 (older kernel) does. That's a huge bug. Just in case this save you some time. Bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1424491)

Answer (score 0):

Run the command:

```
md5sum <download-filename>
```

Then compare the output to the correct version of your download on [this list](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes)

This checks that the file isn't corrupted in any way.

Comment: I run ~$ md5sum ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso                
but it gave c190973e3a522bbc222d2eb20c7f64b0, a very different Hash than that at the list .. So from where do I download a correct ubuntu version ? Thanx

Answer (score -1):

Verify the image's checksum against the one [provided by Ubuntu](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.3/MD5SUMS):

```
b436b6d4c7de064652f30d783bda5b4e  ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso
```

You can calculate the checksum by running `md5sum [file]`.